# Multiple sites on server but only one is down. Possible DNS issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, 500-error, ns-record

I have several sites on a VPS server and one of the sites randomly went down earlier (500 error). The site is hosted on a subdomain of another website that is hosted elsewhere. So, the site that is hosted on my server is blog.example.com while example.com is hosted on another server.

I think the issue is DNS related and possibly NS record related. Prior to the site going down, I had the subdomain website NS records set as my server NS records e.g. ns1.myserver.com and ns2.myserver.com. I thought I might need to change the NS records to the server that is hosting the main website example.com. I changed the NS records to ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com but the problem is still not fixed. Could there be a different problem or another solution?

Comment: Why do you think a 500 Internal Server Error is related to DNS?!

Comment: Literally a shot in the dark. The website wasnt updated/changed and nothing was done to the server.

Comment: DNS seems highly unlikely to be related to this at all. You need to be looking at the server's error logs.

Answer (score 0):

No, the error in question is not, by any chance, DNS related. HTTP error 500 (Internal Server Error) is related with some code/script not running properly.

Take a look at your logs to find out more about the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help. Is the best log to look at the Apache error log? /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log

Comment: Yes, it is. But check and see if you don't have different files for each domain/site.

Comment: Ok, so any thoughts on exactly what I am suppose to be looking for in the error log? It's definitely a problem with WordPress.